# apachebench(ab) append new line for post data

Tags: http, post, performance-testing, apachebench

Trying ab for benchmark testing for post request, but looks post data in file will append a new blank line. Any solution for this issue?

```
$ cat d1
a=1&&b=2
```

ab command is

```
ab -c 1 -n 1 -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded -p d1 -v 2 url
```

Check the post data, find

```
'b': '2\n'
```

Comment: Did my answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue when pasting the text in using Vim. Turns out Vim will, by default, add a new line to the file. See [Why would Vim add a new line at the end of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171254/why-would-vim-add-a-new-line-at-the-end-of-a-file) for reference.

Fixed this by opening the file in Sublime and removing the new line.