# jQuery UI: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to get data using jquery ajax, everything works good and I get what I want, but I can't display it because I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined.

Here the code. Any idea?

```
/*
 * Get the data from the ajax call and display a dialog
 */

function CreateDialog(email) {

    // get the data from the ajax call
    var promise = AjaxSubscribe(email)

    // if data are available, show the dialog
    promise.success(function (data) { 
        // data is a simple html code
        var dialog = $(data);

        // can't setup the dialog! Error
        // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined 
        dialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        dialog.dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
}
```

This is the output of data

```
 console.log(data)

 <p>Data debugging</p>
 <ul>
   <li>Ip address: 193.125.139.18</li>
   <li>Country Name: Italy</li>
   <li>Country Code: IT</li>
   <li>Email: anemail@gmail.com</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: what does `data` contain when it's returned from the ajax call?

Comment: For some reason I don't think `data` is what you think it is. `console.log(data)` and share the output!

Comment: Added the data output at the question. Of course the IP is a fake :D

Answer (score 7):

Try wrapping your data HTML inside a container, either on the backend or the frontend:

```
var dialog = $('<div/>').html(data);
```

I'm not sure `.dialog()` will work on multiple document fragments (you have a `<p>` and a `<ul>` inline). `$(data)` would be an array with 2 elements which is not what `.dialog()` expects.

Comment: This should be the solution.  jQuery UI expects the elements to be in a certain layout and get confused when they are not.

Comment: Right! Thanks for the answer, I add in the backend the div and everything works!

Comment: I had the same problem and the div wrapper was the solution. Actually for me the form was being displayed, but the script was crashing with that same error message right after displaying the form.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure do you not have an empty line at the end of your file. Some editor like Vim add automatically an empty line to respect the POSIX standard [Why would Vim add a new line at the end of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171254/why-would-vim-add-a-new-line-at-the-end-of-a-file)
With Sublime you can show this empty line.