# `mkString` on `BufferedSource` from a file read appends new line character. Is this a desired behavior?

Tags: scala

I created a file with single line:

```
➜  ~ vi some_random_file_mkstring
➜  ~ wc -l < some_random_file_mkstring
       1
```

When I read the file using `Source.fromFile` and create a string using `mkString` it appends a newLine but if I do `.getLines().mkString` it doesn't append a newLine character.

```
scala> io.Source.fromFile("some_random_file_mkstring").mkString
res0: String =
"somerandomstring
"

scala> io.Source.fromFile("some_random_file_mkstring").mkString.contains("\n")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> io.Source.fromFile("some_random_file_mkstring").getLines().mkString.contains("\n")
res2: Boolean = false
```

Is this desired behavior?
I am using scala 2.12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vi` adds a line feed character at the end of files, and `wc` accounts for this. If you do `xxd some_random_file_mkstring` my guess is you'll see a '0a' (\n) at the end.

So given that your file does actually contain that character, this seems like desired behavior to me. `mkString` just takes every character in the file, and `getLines` returns lines without the separator.

For more info about why this is the case, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31426524/854793) has some good context.

Comment: Thanks, echo was also doing the same thing. I used `echo -n > some_file`. Didn't know about this in vi