# Why doesn't the code run with a test.in file created by Sublime TextEditor

Tags: c, macos, file, memory-management, editor

This was a piece of code I have written for my assignment, some of the weird code design are not controllable by me. I am currently writing these on MacOS.

file1

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int read_palindrome();

int main() 
{
    if (read_palindrome()) printf("input is a palindrome");
    else printf("input is not a palindrome");
    return 0;
}
```

file2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int check_palindrome2(char *, int);

// malloc() will be used as usual to set aside an initial memory
// The entire input will be read gradually by characters using getchar()
// In the event we require more memory than what we have previously, 
// use realloc() to increase memory size dynamically

int read_palindrome() {
    unsigned int len_max = 128;
    unsigned int current_size = 0;
    char *pStr = malloc(len_max); 
    current_size = len_max;
    int i = 0;
    int c = EOF;
    if (pStr == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n') { 
        pStr[i] = (char)c;
        i++;
        if(i == current_size) {
            current_size += len_max; 
            char *tmp = realloc(pStr, current_size);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                free(pStr);
                return -1;
            }
            pStr = tmp;
        }
    }

    int retval = check_palindrome2(pStr,i);
    free(pStr);
    return retval;
}


int check_palindrome2(char *s, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) { 
        if (s[i] != s[length-i-1])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I would think this code works except for empty files, which will cause my program to continuously expect input and not terminate. However, I realised when using Sublime Text, creating a test.in file without pressing "Enter" somehow displays the "non-terminating" behaviour as well, while typing something in vim without pressing "Enter" for a newline still allows the code to work. Does anyone know the reason behind this phenomenon?

Comment: Maybe vim automatically adds a line terminator for the last line of a file?

Comment: And it should be: `while (( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && c!=EOF) `

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oh sorry, this was the version of my code before I included EOF to handle the empty files and the Sublime Text problem case. So I take it that you are not sure of the weird behaviour too?

Comment: It is not weird behavior of SubLime. If the user does not want to terminate the last line of a file with a newline, then that is his choice and may be intentional and/or required for some purpose.

Comment: Then do you know why vim might possibly "automatically add a line terminator"?

Comment: No, I don't know. You must ask the developers. It is all in the requirements (which programmers/developers traditionaly don't write down).

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth I guess the answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171254/why-would-vim-add-a-new-line-at-the-end-of-a-file).