# C++ copying parts of a file to a new file

Tags: c++, file, append, file-handling

I am trying to create a new file with data from two different existing files. I need to copy the first existing file in it's entirety, which I have done successfully. For the second existing file I need to copy just the last two columns and append it to the first file at the end of each row.

Ex:

Info from first file already copied into my new file:

20424297    1092    CSCI    13500   B   3

20424297    1092    CSCI    13600   A-  3.7

Now I need to copy the last two columns of each line in this file and then append them to the appropriate row in the file above:

17   250    3.00    RNL

17   381    3.00    RLA

i.e. I need "3.00" and "RNL" appended to the end of the first row, "3.0" and "RLA" appended to the end of the second row, etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    //Creates new file and StudentData.tsv
    ofstream myFile;
    ifstream studentData;
    ifstream hunterCourseData;

    //StudentData.tsv is opened and checked to make sure it didn't fail
    studentData.open("StudentData.tsv");
    if(studentData.fail()){

       cout << "Student data file failed to open" << endl;
       exit(1);
    }


    //My new file is opened and checked to make sure it didn't fail
    myFile.open("file.txt");
    if(myFile.fail()){

        cout << "MyFile file failed to open" << endl;
        exit(1);

    }

    //HunterCourse file is opened and checked to make sure if didn't   fail
    hunterCourseData.open("HunterCourse.tsv");
    if(myFile.fail()){

        cout << "Hunter data file failed to open" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Copies data from StudentData.tsv to myFile
    char next = '\0';
    int n = 1;

        while(! studentData.eof()){

        myFile << next;
        if(next == '\n'){

            n++;
            myFile << n << ' ';

        }
        studentData.get(next);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am going bananas trying to figure this out. I'm sure it's a simple fix but I can't find anything online that works. I've looked into using ostream and a while loop to assign each row into a variable but I can't get that to work.

Another approach that has crossed my mind is just to remove all integers from the second file because I only need the last two columns and neither of those columns include integers.

Comment: 1. It looks like you wan to get the last `column` of the second file; 2. Do you really need to use C++? If you're on Linux, you can use a lot of utils to achieve the goal, e.g. `awk`.

Comment: Sounds like you want to copy the last two columns, not the last two rows. The rows are the acrossy things the columns are the uppie-downy things.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the heads up. I meant columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [the seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) method of a file-stream, you'll note the second version allows you to implement the location to set an offset from (such as `ios_base::end` which sets the offset compared to the end of the file. With this you can effectively read backwards from the end of the a file.
Consider the following

```
int Pos=0;
while(hunterCourseData.peek()!= '\n')
{
    Pos--;
    hunterCourseData.seekg(Pos, ios_base::end);
}
//this line will execute when you have found the first newline-character from the end of the file.
```

Much better code is available at this [Very Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876290/c-fastest-way-to-read-only-last-line-of-text-file)

Another possibility is simply to find how many lines are in the file beforehand. (less fast, but workable), in this case one would simply loop though the file calling `getline` and increment a count variable, reset to the start, then repeat until reaching the `count - 2`. Though I wouldn't use this technique myself.