# Arduino read last line from SD Card

Tags: c++, arduino, sd-card

I am pretty new to Arduino business. How do I read the last line from a SD Card? With following code snippet I can read the first line (all characters before "\n"). Now I would like to include a "backwards" statement (or something).

My code so far:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

File SD_File;

int pinCS = 10;

char cr;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SD.begin();

  SD_File = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);  
  SD_File.println("hello");
  SD_File.close();

  SD_File = SD.open("test.txt");
  while(true){
    cr = SD_File.read();
    if((cr == '\n') && ("LAST LINE?"))
        break;
    Serial.print(cr);
    }
  SD_File.close();

}

void loop() {

}
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are  you looking for [`available()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileAvailable) or [`peek()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FilePeek)? Note that last line does not necessarily end with `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are technically opening text files, you could use seekg to jump to the end of the file and read the last line, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876290/c-fastest-way-to-read-only-last-line-of-text-file).

If this is not helpful, adding a bit more context and an example file would help us understand your question better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I implement seekg? Which library does it belong to? When I try to upload the code on my DUE it gives only error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question.

- *"How do I implement `seekg`?"* There is not [`seekg`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg). There is however, a [`seek`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileSeek).
- [This](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD) is the documentation page for the SD library. In the right side of the page there is a list of all `File` class methods (`seek` among others).
- *" How do I read the last line..."* There is no line reading in your code. If you just want to go to the end of file use: `SD_File.seek( SD_File.size() );` If you want to read the last line, the simplest way is to write a `getline` function and read the whole file line by line until end. Assuming `MAX_LINE` is **large enough** and `getline` returns zero on success:

```
//...
char s[ MAX_LINE ];
while ( getline( f, s, MAX_LINE , '\n' ) == 0 )
  ;

// when reaching this point, s contains the last line
Serial.print( "This is the last line: " );
Serial.print( s );
```

Here's a `getline` idea (no warranty - not tested):

```
/*
  s     - destination
  count - maximum number of characters to write to s, including the null terminator. If 
          the limit is reached, it returns -2.
  delim - delimiting character ('\n' in your case)

  returns:
     0 - no error
    -1 - eof reached
    -2 - full buffer
*/
int getline( File& f, char* s, int count, char delim )
{
  int ccount = 0;
  int result = 0;
  if ( 0 < count )
    while ( 1 )
    {
      char c = f.peek();
      if ( c == -1 )
      {
        f.read(); // extract
        result = -1;
        break;  // eof reached
      }
      else if ( c == delim )
      {
        f.read(); // extract
        ++ccount;
        break; // eol reached
      }
      else if ( --count <= 0 )
      {
        result = -2;
        break; // end of buffer reached
      }
      else
      {
        f.read(); // extract
        *s++ = c;
        ++ccount;
      }
    }

  *s = '\0'; // end of string
  return ccount == 0 ? -1 : result;
}
```